# Where does EMR store Spark stdout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I am running my Spark application on EMR, and have several println() statements. Other than the console, where do these statements get logged?

My S3 aws-logs directory structure for my cluster looks like:

`node
├── i-0031cd7a536a42g1e
│   ├── applications
│   ├── bootstrap-actions
│   ├── daemons
│   ├── provision-node
│   └── setup-devices
containers/
├── application_12341331455631_0001
│   ├── container_12341331455631_0001_01_000001`

Comment: Viewing log files: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html

Answer (score 14):

You can find println's in a few places:

- Resource Manager -> Your Application -> Logs -> stdout
- Your S3 log directory -> `containers/application_.../container_.../stdout` (though this takes a few minutes to populate after the application)
- SSH into the EMR, `yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -log_files <log_file_type>`

Comment: None of these places is showing my output to stdout (and it's definitely in the Spark driver, not a lambda exported to the executors). I also can't seem to add anything to the logs at any log level using Log4j or Log4j2. Black hole.

Comment: where is the resource manager for a EMR cluster? Like @nclark I haven't found my output in any of this locations

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html - you want the resource manager on port 8088, it may require some browser configuration

Answer (score 3):

There is a very important thing that you need to consider when printing from Spark: **are you running code that gets executed in the driver or is it code that runs in the executor?**

For example, if you do the following, it will output in the console as you are bringing data back to the driver:

```
for i in your_rdd.collect():
    print i
```

But the following will run within an executor and thus it will be written in the Spark logs:

```
def run_in_executor(value):
    print value

your_rdd.map(lambda x: value(x))
```

Now going to your original question, the second case will write to the log location. Logs are usually written to the master node which is located in /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps, but it might be better to configure logs to an s3 bucket with --log-uri. That way it will be easier to find.

Comment: is it not: `your_rdd.map(lambda x: run_in_executor(x))` you want on that final line?